# Split the string

Tags: java, android, string

abcd+xyz

i want to split the string and get left and right components with respect to "+"

that is i need to get abcd and xyz seperatly.
I tried the below code.

```
String org  = "abcd+xyz";   
String splits[] = org.split("+");
```

But i am getting null value for splits[0] and splits[1]...

Please help..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The string you send as an argument to `split()` is interpreted as a regex ([documentation for `split(String regex)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)). You should add an escape character before the + sign:

```
String splits[] = org.split("\\+");
```

You might also find the [Summary of regular-expression constructs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) worth reading :)

Comment: `\\+` otherwise it won't work (I'm not sure it will compile).

Comment: @Nailuj tanks ... i tried that with a slight modification.. String splits[] = org.split("\\+");

Comment: @khachik: yeah, of course, I forgot you have to escape the \ as well, thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

"+" is wild character for regular expression. 
So just do

> String splits[] = org.split("\\+");

This will work

Answer (score 2):

the expression "+" means one or many in java regular expression.
split takes Regex as a argument hence the comparion given by you fails 
So use

String org  = "abcd+xyz";
String splits[] = org.split(""\+");

regards!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String splits[] = org.split("\\+");
```